# cannot insert and save data to a table connected to postgresql on window forms

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms

I cannot insert and save data on a table in my window forms program.

The code on window forms is:

```
private void BtnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rowIndex = -1;
            textIdentificacao.Enabled = textNome.Enabled = true;
            textIdentificacao.Text = textNome.Text = null;
            textIdentificacao.Select();

        }


private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int result = 0;
            if (rowIndex < 0)//insert
            {

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    sql = @"Select * from insert(:_docente_id,:_nome_docente)";
                    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_docente_id", textIdentificacao.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_nome_docente", textNome.Text);                  
                    result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    conn.Close();
                    if (result == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Inserido com sucesso.");
                        Select();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Inserção falhou.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Inserção falhou. Error:" + ex.Message);

                }

            }
            result = 0;
            textIdentificacao.Text = textNome.Text = null;
            textIdentificacao.Enabled = textNome.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

the function in posgresql is:

```
create or replace function insert(_docente_id int, _nome_docente varchar)
returns int as
$$
begin
    insert into docente(docente_id, nome_docente)
    values(_docente_id, _nome_docente);
    if found then
    return 1;
    else return 0;
    end if;
end
$$
language plpgsql
```

The error is:
error 42883 function insert(text, text) does not exist

I think the problem is connected with the int and text.
Because the function in postgresql has one int and one varchar and in c# I'm using
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_docente_id", textIdentificacao.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_nome_docente", textNome.Text);

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching your line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_docente_id", textIdentificacao.Text)
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("_docente_id", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["_docente_id"].Value = int.Parse(textIdentificacao.Text);
```

or even just `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_docente_id", int.Parse(textIdentificacao.Text));`

Comment: Hi Guru, I still don't have enough reputation but I will once I have it. I tried several times but it doesn't let me mark.

Comment: @RaquelWill0 interesting, NP =)

Comment: :) I was able to rate you. Thank you @gurustron

Comment: @RaquelWill0 NP. Was glad to help!